# Two Select from different table in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to return two columns ('question' and 'reponse') from two different table (also named 'question' and 'reponse') using a createQueryBuilder. I have no problem when I return one column, but it doesn't work when I try adding a new Select option.

My Controller that render my view and the data correctly :

```
 public function play(Request $request) {

    $id = $request->query->get('id');

    $cat = $this->repository->findIdQuestion($id);


    return $this->render('quiz_select.html.twig', [
        'question' => $cat
    ]);
```

Here is my Question Repository that works when I remove the 'addSelect'

What can I do ?

```
public function findIdQuestion($id) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('question')
            ->addSelect('reponse')
            ->from('App\Entity\Reponse', 'reponse')
            ->where('question.id_categorie = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
  }
```

I get that Error :

```
`An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT q0_.id AS id_0, q0_.id_categorie AS id_categorie_1, q0_.question AS question_2, r1_.id AS id_3, r1_.id_question AS id_question_4, r1_.reponse AS reponse_5, r1_.reponse_expected AS reponse_expected_6, r1_.question_id AS question_id_7 FROM question q0_, reponse r1_ WHERE q0_.id_categorie = ?' with params ["2"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'r1_.question_id' in 'field list'`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what do you want to do. But I suppose you want to get a **question** and the **reponse** related to this question.

For doing that, you need to make a join between those tables.
You can use for example leftJoin

```php
$query->leftjoin('App\Entity\Reponse','reponse','WITH','reponse.id = question.reponse_id')
```

Note that i supposed that there is reponse_id in you question table. 
Be free to replace it by what you want.

For more precisions, you can check doctrine documentation.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/index.html

There a lot of examples, tutorials and a fully documentation

[Edited] 
Problem there was that the field question_id was not in the table question in the database

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I added this line but I still get the same error. I have a 'question' table (with only questions) and a 'reponse' table (with answers only) And I would like to show the answers related to each question. However my query here only seems to return the question but not the answers.

Comment: are you sure that there is a field "question_id" in your reponse table in your sql database ? check the syntax, and check in your entity reponse if the syntax is correct too

Comment: I ended up creating one, I still don't know why it wanted me to have that field in my database. I'm now facing a new error `Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string`

Comment: I suppose that in your Entity reponse, you have an attribute question_id, because you use an ORM all fields are mapped from database table. The error there is that you try to use the return of your function directly as a string but your function doesn’t return string.